# Pi boots to a white login screen instead of desktop after making tightvncserver boot at startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, vnc, init

I installed tightvncserver, started the service, logged in remotely with no issues.  I created a file in `/etc/init.d/` called vncboot.

```bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
  echo "Starting VNC Server"
  #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
  /usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1440x900 -depth 24 
  /usr/bin/vncserver :2 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16 
  ;;

 stop)
  echo "Stopping VNC Server"
  /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :0
  ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I ran the file several times and it worked just fine.  It started and stopped the service as it was supposed to.
Then I added the file to start with the raspberry pi with

```
sudo update-rc.d vncboot
```

After this the screen goes to white login screen asking for login, password, and a dropdown list with: Default Xsession, LXDE, OpenBox.  When I put in the correct login the screen goes black, then back to the login page.  If I put in incorrect login info, I get a prompt that says incorrect.

I can ssh into the machine just fine. 
Any ideas of what happened or how I can fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Update - This post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=36114 helped me.
I used Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get login prompt, df -h to check size,  finally sudo startx to bring up the gui
However, when I restart, it still goes to that white screen.

Comment: Why are you starting two extra vnc servers on DISPLAYs numbered :1 and :2 with different screen resolutions with the "start" script action (which seems reasonable) but killing the primary one that a local user will be using (on DISPLAY :0) with the "stop" action?  Note: now that the default Jessie install of Raspbian uses `systemd` rather that SysV `init` the way you invoke `tightvnc` may need revising... 8-(

Answer (score 2):

changing the ownership of .Xauthority file should fix the issue.

```
$sudo su
#chown pi:pi .Xauthority
#reboot
```

After reboot, the login prompt doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  I followed these directions ([here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=27905)) which are . . .

```
cd ~
ls -l -a
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bkp
```

If you reboot, should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can give `xrdp` a try. I have used it some time before and it worked very nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem and got it solved by using the following commands:

```
cd ~
ls -l -a
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bkp
```

After reboot, the login prompt doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was because I did not have enough memory. Do the following

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```